# Xamarin.Forms when i try to call a number containing asterisk and hashtag the hashtag is not appearing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms when i try to call a number containing asterisk  and hashtag the hashtag is not appearing, can any one please help me?

my Xamarin source code

```
private void BtnCall_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {    
        var PhoneCallTask = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;    
        if (PhoneCallTask.CanMakePhoneCall)
        var number ="*220*4651599*3000#"; 
            PhoneCallTask.MakePhoneCall (number);    
    }
```

[when i run how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e5I4.png)

[What i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbvf1.png)

thank you

Comment: I do not think you can do it with the plugin, Looks like they try to format the number before displaying it, best solution is write your own implementation with custom renderr.

Comment: do you have any idea about how to implement this kind of rendering?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the xamarin forms inbuilt API for this and that would work better something like this:

```
  private void BtnCall_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)    
    { 
       Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel:*220*4651599*3000#"));
    }
```

Check if this works and in case it doesn't feel free to revert

Comment: so where i can but this one

Comment: Directly in your PCL project check my updated answer

Comment: still there is no hashtag

Comment: Okay let me check i will find something and let you know soon